# How to integrate paypal with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I've website where uses can request for payment and i also have a paypal business account.So when user request for payment that money will cut off from my business account and will be added to their personal account.

How can I do that.Any code sample will be highly appreciable

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Comment: Voted to close as it's an off-topic question for StackOverflow (_so expect it to be closed_). For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then, if you are sure your question fits the SO rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any Laravel package for integration with paypal payment, there is a sample code in docs.
https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, you should AVOID answering (_also on comments_) **code and tutorial requests**, **unclear**, **overly-broad**, **typos**, **opinion-based**, **duplicate**, **non-programming-related** and all **off-topic**  questions. Answering inappropriate questions harms the site by making it more difficult to navigate to find appropriate results **and what is worst, encouraging further such questions**. Vote to close it instead will help SO and educate it's users to use it correctly. PS: It's your choice, but if you delete the answer you will recover the repo :-)

Comment: i read this,but i dont think it will server my purpose.I just need to send money from my account to other users account.Not get money from their account to my account